# Getting BindingExpression path error in output window, but bindings work fine

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In out project, we use MVVM and WPF. 
To bind View and View Model, we use another class and call it presenter. This presenter class binds View and View model, so we can bind view to different view models. I am setting Data context of view to viewmodel inside this class.

```
class presenter
{
     // in constructor or any method
     ViewModel = new ViewModelCls();
     View = new ViewXAMLName();

     View.DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```

Now, the problem is, I am using ContentControl in one window, say abc.xaml and setting its content to presenter.View.

```
<ContentControl  Content="{Binding SelectedOption.Presenter.View}"></ContentControl>
```

When I run my project, all binding works fine and Presenter.View gets populated with Presenter.ViewModel. But in output window, I can see many binding errors for the properties present in Presenter.ViewModel.

I tried to debug and found out  that for SelectedOption.Presenter.View, it sets DataContext to ViewModel of abc.xaml and tries to find properties in that View model. But obviously, it cannot find it and writes all those binding error in output window. Later on, it  sets the VM to the "Presenter.ViewModel" and everything works fine.

Is there any way to remove those Binding errors from Output window?? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does it matter for you to see these binding error? They are correct aren't they initially the binding could not be established. You can try to update your source to do databinding at appropriate time

Answer (score 0):

The Data Binding errors can be suppressed by setting the binding source level to Critical.

```
System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.Critical;
```

[More information on this.](http://weblogs.asp.net/akjoshi/resolving-un-harmful-binding-errors-in-wpf)